# deformation on Gazebo and ROS, possible?

Tags: ros, gazebo, bullet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i'm working with ROS electric , and Gazebo, and i'm working on colission detection , and now i'm wanna go one step more, i mean, make deformation between objects. I know that exist a library Call BUllet 3D and is used for Gazebo_plugins, i don't know exactly when , and how, the bullet 3D supports Soft body support including cloth, rope and deformable but it's possible make something or add the functions of bullet about deformable on Gazebo? how can i do that? .

Pd: where are examples of using ROS and Bullet ?? on ROS don't find anything

thnks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57900/deformation-on--gazebo-and-ros,-possible?/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will have to wait until those changes have been (1) released by gazebo, and then (2) appear in the next ROS distribution.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2013-03-12**:
ok thnks, well i have to search other options, the reallly is that i'm need these now, is a project that i vae to present, sad, cause i wanted all implementig on gazebo and ros, but well nothing to do for now, make the deformable with windows and visual or i don't know . thnks for the answer.